# How to set a min font size in electron?

Tags: fonts, electron, font-size

I need to set a minimum `font-size` in our electron app, just like Chrome has a default `12px` min font-size.

But I can not find any params to set this attribute.

Comment: See also https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a new [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) with [options](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions), you can add a `webPreferences` property which is an object literal, containing properties named `minimumFontSize`, `defaultFontSize`, `defaultMonospaceFontSize`, etc. For instance:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
{
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences:
    {
        minimumFontSize: 18,
        defaultFontSize: 24,
        defaultMonospaceFontSize: 20
    }
});
```

Note that the actual default font sizes may be overridden by any CSS already defined though.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I want!

Comment: My whole app styling is `rem` based and setting this font size adjusted whole app size accordingly. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies, that the user can change the font size in your application.

What you may do is work with css variables, e. g.:

```js
//inside my change font-size function

//1. get user set new value
var _new_user_val = 9; //px
//2. check it against your min font-size
if (_new_user_val >= 8) {
 //3. change the css var
 document.body.style.setProperty('--main-font-size', _new_user_val + 'px');
 
} else {
 //4. new user val too low - error out
 print_error("not allowed, min font size is 8px");
}
```

```css
:root {
    --main-font-size: 12px; 
}

p {
    font-size: var(--main-font-size); 
}
```

```html
<p>My Text</p>
```